# Should I use singleton everytime I have a class that should have only 1 instance?

Tags: java, oop, singleton

Many times i have a class that should have only 1 instance. Is the best practice is to use singleton?

Comment: That's what singleton is for. The question is whether you `need` to have a single instance or just happened to right some code that uses only one instance and doesn't require for more. The first case is a singleton, for the second a simple class is enough.

Comment: Singleton is the definition of what you describe.

Comment: Absolutely not.  If you're using lots of singletons you're not designing your application correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Singletons are global state. They should be used only when it's really necessary, for the same reason that your code shouldn't have a ton of global variables.

"Should have" is the operative question. If the system doesn't care how many instances there are, don't make it a singleton. Only if the system truly requires that there be only one instance should you be thinking singleton.

Answer (score 4):

Another pattern you can use is a factory method.
The advantage here is that the factory may decide to return the same instance every time
or a new instance.
This will impose less limitations if you someday choose you don't want just a single instance, but let's say for example -  a single instance per thread.

Comment: If you do this, don't call the factory method getSingleton()!

Comment: Damn , I wish somebody would have told me this earlier :-)

Comment: I'm not saying you do it, but I very often see people commit to singletons even though they're using the static factory. Totally confuses me.

Comment: I know, was just joking

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use a dependency injection framework like Spring or Guice. Many people think that Singleton is rather an antipattern than a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience , In most cases (atleast in my case :)) a singleton is equivalent to a class consisting only of static `attributes` and `methods`.

The `singleton pattern` is a simpler way of slowing down the system by  implementing `syncronization`.

Don't go for it unless you need it.

If you are ok with multiple `instances` go for it,Other wise go for dependency `injection`.

A good article [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-so-bad-about-the-singleton/) read few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

An additional answer I've just found on other sources.

Singleton is good to use when you should access the same one instance from multiple parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern is a design solution where an application wants to have one and only one instance of any class, in all possible scenarios without any exceptional condition.
[image]

[For More Click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)